# Google Cloud Platform Appscript JDBC connection to sqlserver in same GCP

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, jdbc

I am new in appscript and jdbc.

I used the following jdbc connection string to try to connect to MS SQL hosted in the same GCP account:

*"jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserverip;databaseName=testdb;user=tester; password=mypassword "*

but received the following error :

"Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."

I have combed through the web, only found users facing the same problem with mysql and not sqlserver (MS SQL). I have try to create a mysql instance in gcp it has no problem connecting (using mysql version of connection string).

anybody facing this same issue on sqlserver ?
I am not sure where I should check further.
I have try various connection string but all return the same error.
I have configured my network access for my IP (I am able to connect to the sqlserver using SSMS from laptop)

My SQL version is MS SQL Web Edition 2017.

thanks

Comment: What's the version of the JDBC driver you're using? JDBC Driver 10.2 for SQL Server and later changed a default connection property from `Encrypt=No;` to `Encrypt=Yes;` which means that it will fail to connect to SQL Server instances using a self-signed certificate (which, as it happens, is the normal case for new instances)... unless you also change other connection properties to suit.

Comment: may I know how to get JDBC driver version ? this is in google cloud platform, I just followed appscript documentation example.

Comment: I include Encrypt=No and it return another new error message "The following connection properties are unsupported: Encrypt. "

Comment: Sorry, JDBC probably uses true/false instead of yes/no. Refer to [JDBC Driver 10.2 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/jdbc-driver-10-2-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3100754) and [Building the connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url).

Comment: I tried both True and False , still got the same error message. 
"The following connection properties are unsupported: Encrypt."